# MVC Redirect to another Controller In different namespace, but same project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have differnt controllers in my Website, Some of them are in  WebSite/Controller folder and some are in Website/Area/Test/Controllers.

When I hit Website/Controller/Home/Index, I want to redirect the user to Website/Area/Test/Controller/Home/Index with Query string PArameter.

Here's is my first Controller

```
namespace mySite.Controllers
{
 public partial class HomeController : BaseFrontController
    {
     public virtual ActionResult Index()
        {          
            var issuburl = channelRepository.GetChannelByUrl('UserID');
            if (issuburl != null)
                return Redirect("~/Areas/Test/Controllers/Index");

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my Second Controller

```
namespace mySite.Areas.Test.Controllers
{
 public partial class HomeController : BaseTestController
    {
     public virtual ActionResult Index(string param)
        {          
            var chn = rep1.GetChannel(param);
            if (chn != null)
            {
                model.Chn = chn;
            }
            else return Redirect("~/Error/Index");      
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

my Error Controller is in Mysite/Controller folder and I can access it inside MySite/Area/Test/Controller, but How can I access  Mysite/Controller controller inside 
MySite/Area/Test/Controller

Below code is not working

```
return Redirect("~/Areas/Test/Controllers/Index");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "controller", new { area = "Test" });
```

It is using [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460311%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

To specify different parameters you can use

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "controller", new { area = "Test", yourParam1 = "param1", yourParam2 = "param2" });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "controller", new { area = "Test" });
```